# How to auto generate biblioographies

Tags: 7, nodes

I currently have a content type called book, where the book has fields: author name, book title, ISBN , publication date, ect.

I'd like to automatically generate a bibliography entry for each book so that users can copy and paste it easily. Is there a module that can do this? I know of the biblio module, but to the best of my knowledge you must directly input the information.

So is there a way to automatically generate a bibliography citation entry for a given book based off of the book's given fields?

Comment: where do you want to display the information, and what all do you want to do with it once it's created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into views https://drupal.org/project/views and you can display your content anyway that you want to display it. There is a small learning curve but displaying content type fields is one of the easiest forms of a view to setup. There are tons of examples setup and disabled by default from many modules so chances are you already have views code somewhere in your site even if you don't have the actual module yet :) 
Look at the project page under Resources heading to find documentation and tutorials plus there are millions online with quick Google searches.